# how to properly format JSX in the new class (extends component) format

Tags: reactjs

I'm wanting a little bit of code wisdom, not repair.  I learned react one way, and I'm seeing code in a different format.  I'm trying to learn the difference.

I was given this jsx snippet:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../reducers'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props}/>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }}/>
        )
    )}/>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: reducers.isAuthenticated(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

The code works perfectly fine, but I'm trying to understand it.  the lessons I have learned is class-based.

for example:

```
class Logout extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(logout());
    }
    render() {
        return(<Redirect to="/" push={true} />);
    }
}
```

I have two questions about this code:

1. This appears to be a function, is that true?
2. Should this be a class?  and if so, how should it read?

If the code should be a class, and I can see how it should look, then I'll know how to transform the rest of them to be properly coded.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../reducers'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props}/>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }}/>
        )
    )}/>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: reducers.isAuthenticated(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

This is a functional Component. You can also call it stateless component.

This can also be written as class based component / stateful component as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../reducers'

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route {...rest} render={() => (
                isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component {...this.props}/>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{
                        pathname: '/login',
                        state: { from: this.props.location }
                    }}/>
                )
            )}/>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: reducers.isAuthenticated(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

Choose to use functional and class based components wisely. Because class based components are heavier as they have lifecycle hooks and state, while functional components are just the business logic.

**What I personally use?**

I follow this pattern. I keep all my rendering logic in small functional components and all the business logic in a Class based Component which will become parent of functional component(s).

Here is an example:

TestContainer.js

```
class TestContainer extends React {
    // state
    // lifecycle hooks
    // events
    // other functions
    render() {
        return <Test />; // pass any props here in Test
    }
}

export default TestContainer; // connect with redux store here (if you want)
```

Test.js

```
const Test = props => (
    // rendering logic
);

export default Test; // don't connect to redux store here. if you want something from redux store, then connect the parent to redux store and get data from parent(TestContainer) as props.
```

Comment: so, you are saying, that unless I'm changing state, stick with functional components?

Comment: @arcee123 Yes I mean that